# Java - Get a matrix of pixel values from an image

Tags: java, image, matrix

Good evening,

I'm loading an image in Java using BufferedImage. I'd to convert this Object in a simple 2D matrix where every cell is an 8 bit pixel value (from 0 to 255).
This needs to work with grayscale images but also with RGB images (in this case the output needs to be 3 matrixes, one for each channel, or a single 3D matrix).
This is similar to how MatLab handles images.

Anyone that can help me?

Thank you

Comment: The javadoc to BufferedImage offers methods getRGB(x,y), getWidth() and getHeight(). What else do you need?

Comment: See this SO post: [java-image-conversion-to-a-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627006/java-image-conversion-to-a-matrix)

Comment: I tried getRGB but it doesn’t give me 8 bit integers. It’s more like 16 bit integers with sign or something like that

Comment: How would an RGB value fit into 8 bits?  (There are some ColorModels/X-Windows visuals which support this, but I don’t know if they match what you have in mind.)

Comment: As I said, I'd like to have 3 2D matrixes, one for each channel. So every pixel of every matrix should have a value from 0 to 255. A single channel pixel value fits 8 bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
BufferedImage bf = //Assuming you have a buffered image
int[][] R = new int[bf.getWidth()][bf.getHeight()];
int[][] G = //Same as for R
int[][] B = //Same as for R

for(int r = 0; r < bf.getWidth(); r++)
{
     for(int c = 0; c < bf.getHeight() c++)
     {
           //Uses the Java color class to do the conversion from int to RGB
           Color temp = new Color(bf.getRGB(r, c));
           R[r][c] = temp.getRed();
           G[r][c] = temp.getGreen();
           B[r][c] = temp.getBlue();
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you. This works. And for grayscale photos I can use something like
int p = rasterData.getSample(x, y, 0); (channel 0 is for the luminance values of a grayscale image)